# Datetime int float, why we can go to float but not to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, int

When casting a Datetime to a float you get the offset as a float.
Converting that to a int only gives part of the date.
So far so good, we have a trimmed date when we go back to datetime

Doing the same and converting directly to int
and back to datetime only works some of the time.

Mainly for use in sql server

Code:

```
CONVERT(datetime,floor(CONVERT(float,START_TIME_1)))
```

Not working:

```
CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(Int,START_TIME_1))
```

Anyone know why this is?

I was given the answer to this question by "Mikael Eriksson" ->
"That is because when converting from datetime to int the value is rounded to the nearest int. Datetime values with a time part equal or greater than 12:00 will be rounded up to the next integer/day."

Obviously this is by now an outdated question due to support of the cast and convert function now being everywhere.
Not to mention that datetime2 should be used.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: Without more information - ideally language/platform + sample code with sample data - this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: CONVERT(datetime,floor(CONVERT(float,START_TIME_1)))

Comment: But going directly to int doesn't work

Comment: Just to clarify. Does "Not working" here mean the the date sometimes when converting to `int` is returning the next day as in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14599)?

Comment: When converting to int the value is rounded to the nearest integer where 12:00 (noon) is `.5` and rounded up. When converting to float that does of course not happen and then you use floor to make sure you end up with the same date regardless of the time part.

Comment: I have no idea (yet) why a datetime converted to int rounds up for times >= 12:00. But to do what you want here in SQL Server 2008 you should use the `date` datatype instead. `cast(STARt_TIME_1 as date)`.

Comment: The support of date is only 'recent', I used float to avoid that problem. Otherwise that is indeed a cleaner version of my code

Comment: The alternative if you need to support SQL Server 2005 is to use `select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)`.

Comment: The error gave me the first of the next month due to rounding after 12h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the time part in SQL Server 2005 you can use this:

```
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

From SQL Server 2008 you can use the date datatype instead.

```
select cast(getdate() as date)
```

Casting to `float` and using the `floor` function also works as you have seen but I think the above alternatives is to prefer.

Your question was why a cast to `integer` sometimes return the wrong value.

That is because when converting from `datetime` to `int` the value is rounded to the nearest `int`. `Datetime` values with a time part equal or greater than 12:00 will be rounded up to the next integer/day.

The behaviour is documented in [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in the section "Truncating and Rounding Results".

Answer (score -1):

Language used?

Try casting it into `Long` or equivalent big integer.

Comment: Tried a bigint but only a float works, so it is not. due to size limits of int

Comment: Language used??????????

Comment: Mmm, sorry. No experience with Micro$oft sql sever in last 10 years :S. Publish your code if you want someone (else) to be able to help you.